# vb6 button that contain execute function in other form

Tags: vb6

I tried hard and make double clicked event

that form to psa33

and form is successfully change and data that i want to send is attached

but two problems left

1. after form change(psa33) then automatically execute function at psa33 how can i code it ?
2. there's another form at project , form name is psa34 but it s not in form list so i found this code at psa 33

```
    Select Case UCase(Me.gPGM_ID)
    Case "PSA33"
        fltTot_Qty.Text = Sum_Qty
        fltTot_Amt.Text = Sum_Amt
        flttot_amt_f.Text = Sum_Amt_F
        fltTot_Vat.Text = Sum_Vat
    Case "PSA34"
        fltTot_Qty.Text = Abs(Sum_Qty) * (-1)
        fltTot_Amt.Text = Abs(Sum_Amt) * (-1)
        flttot_amt_f.Text = Abs(Sum_Amt_F) * (-1)
        fltTot_Vat.Text = Sum_Vat
    End Select
```

i think this kind of code change psa33 to psa34  but i dont know how it works exactly

```
Private Sub ListView1_DblClick()
      
    Dim MyForm As Form
      If ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(8) > 0 Then
        Set MyForm = New PSA33
         MyForm.txtChul_No.Text = ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(1).Text
         MyForm.datChul_Date = ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(11)
         MyForm.cmbSaup_Gubn.Text = cmbSaup_Gubn.Text
        Load MyForm 
         '(it works well until here)'
        'Call PSA33.fnDataFind ( I want use fnDataFind function at form psa33 but it doesnt' work)  

     Else

       'Set MyForm = New PSA34 (there's no psa34 so but it's view  is almost same like psa 33 so i found above code at  psa 33)
         'MyForm.txtChul_No.Text = ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(1).Text
         'MyForm.datChul_Date = ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(11)
         'MyForm.cmbSaup_Gubn.Text = cmbSaup_Gubn.Text
        'Load MyForm

          'Call PSA33.fnDataFind (i Think it must change because not form psa33 ) 
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim MyForm As Form
      If ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(8) > 0 Then
        Set MyForm = New PSA33
         MyForm.txtChul_No.Text = ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(1).Text
         MyForm.datchul_Date = ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(11)
         MyForm.cmbsaup_gubn.Text = cmbsaup_gubn.Text
        'MyForm.txtdest_cust = ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(5).Text
        'MyForm.txtcust_code = ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(5).Text
        Load MyForm
        Call MyForm.fnDataFind
     Else
       Set MyForm = New PSA33
         MyForm.gPGM_ID = "PSA34"
         MyForm.txtChul_No.Text = ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(1).Text
         MyForm.datchul_Date = ListView1.SelectedItem.ListSubItems(11)
         MyForm.cmbsaup_gubn.Text = cmbsaup_gubn.Text
        Load MyForm
        Call MyForm.fnDataFind
    End If
```

Comment: This Code Works perfectly that  I want .  I hope this code helps you all